# Is it okay to collect input tuples using a loop by adding to an outer tuple instead of appending to a list?

Tags: python

For my program, I am inputting a 2 dimensional array that is **read a lot of times later in it but never changed**. I know that tuples are faster if I'm only reading values.

Here's the code to input by using lists:

```py
n = 3 # sample value
grid = []
for i in range(n):
    grid.append(tuple(map(int, input().split())))
```

And here's the code to input by using tuples:

```py
n = 3 # sample value
grid = ()
for i in range(n):
    grid += (tuple(map(int, input().split())),)
```

Note: The input is provided in this format:

```
1 0 0
0 0 0
0 0 1
```

which results in the list `[(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1)]`, respectively the tuple `((1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1))`.

From my testing the total time of the program was higher when using tuples. Is there even a better way to input tuples?

Here's the whole code:

```py
n, m = list(map(int, input().split()))
grid = []
for i in range(n):
    grid.append(tuple(map(int, input().split())))

def t2nh(st):
    t = len(grid) + len(grid[0])
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        for j in range(len(grid[i])):
            if grid[i][j] == 1:
                t = min(abs(i+1 - st[0]) + abs(j+1 - st[1]), t)
    return t

t = 0
for i in range(len(grid)):
    for j in range(len(grid[i])):
        t += t2nh([i+1, j+1])

print(t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course your second approach is going to be slower. `tuple`s are immutable which means whenever you add a new tuple using `grid += (tuple(map(int, input().split())),)`, Python doesn't/can't mutate the tuple but is going to create a *new* tuple object by concatenating these two. That is not the case with `list`s.

It only puts the (reference to the) new tuple into the list. Normally it already has available space to insert them because of the ["over-allocation"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c#L61) thing.

I think the fastest way would be using a list comprehension as it's slightly faster than loop + append:

```py
grid = [tuple(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n)]
```

But you're dealing with a very small data. It "*really*" doesn't matter. You won't see any difference in terms of speed.

Comment: The data I gave was just a sample, and the actual testing contains much larger data apparently. Also, will the method you gave be impactfully slower than inputting a list?

Comment: @AbsoluteReality You mean a list of lists instead of a list of tuples ?

Comment: Yeah, I meant a list of lists, my bad

Comment: @AbsoluteReality No I believe there shouldn't be noticeable difference. Maybe a few milliseconds in million iteration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your second method is that it's creating a new tuple during each iteration, just to throw it away the next time.

Use the first method, then convert the final list to a tuple. Or use a generator:

```
grid = tuple(tuple(map(int, input().split())) for _ in range(n))
```